# when self-hosted Sentry， should I run ./install.sh everytime after I restart my computer？

Tags: javascript

So sorry， my English is so poor，hope you can understand what i mean。

I follow the documentation build self-hosted sentry：https://develop.sentry.dev/self-hosted/

It works before I restart my computer.
now, I sent Error to my service but dashboard not show my error.

I guess, my docker configuration occur some problems。

This time I only run `docker-compose up -d`

Not run `./install.sh`

should i run `./install.sh` everytime？

I have been looking for problems for a long time， but they haven't been solved. please help me.

Answer (score 0):

After many experiments, it is found that:

Generally speaking, run it once. However, when the docker status is abnormal. Rerun can solve many unexpected problems